# $\ker g\cap \ker h \subset \ker f$ prove that $f=ag+bh$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a vector space. $f,g,h:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are 3
> linear functionals  statisfies $\ker g\cap \ker h \subset \ker f$.
> Prove that exsist $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=ag+bh$.

I know an easier problem that: if $\ker g\subset\ker f$ so $f=ag$ with $a\in \mathbb{R}$ (my solution: with $x_o\notin \ker g$ we have $g\left(x-\dfrac{g(x)}{g(x_0)}x_0\right)=0$ so that $f\left(x-\dfrac{g(x)}{g(x_0)}x_0\right)=0$ or $f(x)=ag(x)$ with $a=\dfrac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)}$)

I couldn't handle the original problem with the same technique.

Comment: Post your attempts and though processes please

Comment: Ops, I forgot. I edited. @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose ker $g\,\,\cap$ ker $h$ is properly contained in both ker $g$ and ker $h$ (if not the problem reduces to the simpler problem you mentioned).

Take any basis $B$ of ker $g\,\,\cap$ ker $h$, and extend to a basis of ker $g$ by adding a vector $e_1$.  We can do this because $h$ restricts to a map ker $g\to \mathbb{R}$, with kernel precisely ker $g\,\,\cap$ ker $h$.

Also extend $B$ to a basis of ker $h$ by adding a vector $e_2$, which we can do by the same reasoning.

Then $B\cup \{e_1,e_2\}$ is a basis of $V$, as by construction $B\cup \{e_1\}$ is a basis of ker $g$ and $e_2\notin$ ker $g$.

By hypothesis for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $ag+bh$ agrees with $f$ on $B$. Thus we just need to choose $a,b$ such that:\begin{eqnarray*}
ag(e_2)&=&(ag+bh)(e_2)=f(e_2)\\
bh(e_1)&=&(ag+bh)(e_1)=f(e_1).
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus $$a=\frac{f(e_2)}{g(e_2)},\qquad b=\frac{f(e_1)}{h(e_1)}.$$